# MySQL и JOIN из трех таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, join

Имеем три таблицы **shop**, **category**, **product** в MySQL.

**shop**: **id**, **name**, **url**

**category**: **id**, **shop_id**, **name**, **url**

**product**: **id**, **shop_id**, **category_id**, **price**, **store_address**(тут ENUM из ['ЦУМ','УЮТ'])

По **category.id** необходимо получить **product.id**, **product.price**, **category.name**, **shop.name**

1) Как сделать запрос правильно? Я так понял единственным правильным решением будет JOIN. Не в SQL не в MySQL не силен.

2) Мне кажется **store_address** лучше перенести в таблицу **shop**, а не держать ее в **product**

P.S. Для личного саморазвития, интересует вопрос: Думал лучше 1 раз при запросе брать список категорий и магазинов, и на стороне клиента используя JS менять id на name. Все потому, что плохо понимаю как работает JOIN, не будет ли он для каждой записи дергать запрос к category и shop, что бы узнать его name по id? Решение брать список категорий и магазинов отпало почти сразу, мне кажется данный подход выглядит ужасно. Верно ли, что в данном случае лучше использовать JOIN?

Правка: не нужно искать соответствий есть ли такая категория. Нужно просто вместо **category_id** у **product** вставить **category.name**

Comment: join читаются и осваиваются с нулевыми знаниями примерно за 30 минут. просто посмотрите примеры готовых join. можно воспользоваться поиском по слову join на этом сайте. Но вот со структурой БД что то явно не так. И как поправить сказать невозможно потому что вы совершенно не описали задачу. не ясно что за категории, это категории чего магазинов или продуктов или еще чего то. Что делает поле shop_id в таблице категорий, ваша категория явно зависит от какого то одного магазина ? Если да, то что делает категория в продуктах ?

Comment: И да, очень может быть что store_adress должен быть в shop, особенно если это адрес магазина, а не еще чего то. но это вы опять же не указали. невозмиожно сказать что где должно быть, если не описано как оно в жизни. БД должна отражать ситуацию в жизни, если адрес это именно место положения магазина и у магазина может быть только один адрес, то конечно же и находится он должен в таблице магазинов, так как является его неразрывным свойством

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
 SELECT p.id, p.price, p.img, p.store_address, c.name, s.name FROM product p
        INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN shop s ON p.shop_id = s.id
        WHERE c.id = 170
```

2) Структура БД вопрос слишком общий без конкретных условий. Т.к. я только учусь и пример условный, вопрос не актуален.

Comment: Ну вот, отлично же получилось :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем должно быть примерно так, нужно проверять:

`SELECT product.id, product.price, category.name, shop.name 
FROM category 
 LEFT JOIN shop ON category.shop_id = shop.id 
 LEFT JOIN product ON category_id = product.category_id 
WHERE category.id = $id`

Comment: Зачем вы используете LEFT, он тут не нужен. _Никогда_ не используйте LEFT в случаях, когда у вас действительно не стоит задача выбрать строки левой таблицы вне зависимости от наличия строк во второй. Вы в своем запросе, в случае отсутствия товаров по выбранной категории получите строку только с категорией и NULL в остальных полях, вряд ли это ожидаемый результат

Comment: Исходя из того, что человек написал, о то что не разбирается в запросах, ему могут в будущем понадобиться другие данные, тут и начнутся проблемы. Как следствие лучше заведомо использовать запрос позволяющий получить большие данные. Как следствие в будущем если в будущем человек получит пустой ответ а в базе category данные есть, он будет паниковать. Не думаю что база настолько велика что появятся задержки.

Comment: Уж лучше пусть один раз упрется в то, что строки не выбрались и потом узнает о LEFT и будет использовать когда он нужен. Чем будет получать совершенно неожиданные для себя строки в самые непредсказуемые моменты и тормозящие запросы на ровном месте